# Android Studio, grid layout is never the same

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, grid, android-gridlayout

When I work on Android Studio the grid view look awesome and when I run it in emulator the grid view looks corrupted, and its different in different versions of android.

Can anyone help me to get this solved?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:columnCount="4"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button android:text="$3" />
<Button android:text="$5" />

<Button
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:text="upis"  />

<Button android:text="$10" />
<Button android:text="$15" />
<Button android:text="$160" />
<Button android:text="$180" />

<Button android:text="$20" />
<Button android:text="$25" />
<Button android:text="$200" />
<Button android:text="$220" />

<Button android:text="$20" />
<Button android:text="$25" />
<Button android:text="$200" />
<Button android:text="$220" />

<Button android:text="$20" />
<Button android:text="$25" />
<Button android:text="$200" />
<Button android:text="$220" />

<Button android:text="$20" />
<Button android:text="$25" />
<Button android:text="$200" />
<Button android:text="$220" />

<Button android:text="$20" />
<Button android:text="$25" />
<Button android:text="$200" />
<Button android:text="$220" />

<Button android:text="$20" />
<Button android:text="$25" />
<Button android:text="$200" />
<Button android:text="$220" />

<Button android:text="$20" />
<Button android:text="$25" />
<Button android:text="$200" />
<Button android:text="$220" />

</GridLayout>
```

[first emulator pitcure, andriod 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t44ej.png)
[second emulator pitcure, andriod 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Kdc.png)

Can anyone help me with this, or is there any alternative ?

Comment: Your changes have little to do with versions of Android. Mostly, the issue is different screen sizes. You can help the second scenario by having your `GridLayout` fill the available space (`match_parent` for width and height, not `wrap_content` as you have it). You may also need to make some changes to the widget sizing (see "Excess Space Distribution" in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html)).

Answer (score 0):

On your `GridLayout`, try using :

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

The problem of your code is the fact that it doesn't take in account the different screen sizes. Indeed, with

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

the size of the `GridLayout`is taking account of those from the buttons. Since the buttons' sizes aren't defined, the value of `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`are default.